# Is Diffusion model instable during the training?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, python, generative-model, diffusion-models

I ran an experiment using a diffusion model (SR3 model) and got good results (experiment using jupyter notebook). Then, after running the same notebook many times with the same configuration, I did not get the same results.

Is there any explanation for this? Why I did not get the same result for the diffusion model by running the same notebook with the same configurations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is (mostly) because of random weight initialization, each time you instance your model, starting weights are different, and during training the model weights converge to a different local minima.

If you want reproducible results, you should fix the starting weights before training to a fixed value, this is typically done by setting a random seed.

Also note that there are other components that can have stochastic behavior, like dataset shuffling, or giving random inputs to your diffusion model.

Comment: not only weights initialization, but also every other random seed utilized in other classes (like data shuffling, dropout and so on and so forth)

Comment: But the margin is very far. I thought it is related to diffusion model itself?

Comment: I did not fix the seed for other trainings and found that the stability is better

Comment: @ProEns08 Stability can have a lot of meanings in this context, I think you also need to define that. There are many variables that introduce randomness into the training process.

Comment: @EdoardoGuerriero MC-Dropout can affect, but not Dropout, since it is disabled at test time. Other points I agree and I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Snoopy, thanks for the answer